# How to preselect an option in an embedded HTML form?

Tags: camunda

I try to preselect an `option` of a `select` in an embedded HTML form in [Camunda Tasklist](https://camunda.com/products/tasklist/), but always the first option is preselected.

I followed [Binding to a Process Variable](https://docs.camunda.org/manual/7.9/reference/embedded-forms/controls/select/#binding-to-a-process-variable):

> **Binding to a Process Variable**
>
> A select box can be bound to a process variable using the `cam-variable-name` directive:
>
> ```
> <select cam-variable-name="foo" cam-variable-type="String">
>     <option>bar</option>
>     <option>zar</option>
> </select>
> ```

**Research**

I read also [CAM-3173](https://app.camunda.com/jira/browse/CAM-3173):

> **select box doesn't show the correct option**
>
> If I set the value of variable by a select box on the start form, the next task form didn't show the option that has been choosen in the start form. It uses the same select box.

but I use Camunda 7.9 and the problem is fixed since version 7.2.3.

**HTML**

```
<form>
    <select cam-variable-name="variable" cam-variable-type="String">
        <option value="option1">option1</option>
        <option value="option2">option2</option>
    </select>
</form>
```

**Result**

`option1` is preselected. I checked the process variable before entering the user task and it contains `option2`.

What did I wrong? If the bug still exists, is there any work-around?

Answer (score 2):

I found a work-around, see [Camunda Reference](https://docs.camunda.org/manual/7.9/reference/embedded-forms/javascript/lifecycle/#implementing-custom-fields):

> **Implementing Custom Fields**
>
> The following is a small usage example which combines some of the features explained so far. It uses custom JavaScript to implement a custom interaction with a form field which does not use any `cam-variable-*` directives.
>
> It shows how custom scripting can be used for
>
> - declaring a variable to be fetched from the backend,
> - writing the variable’s value to a form field,
> - reading the value upon submit.
>
> [...]
>
> The above example uses jQuery for interacting with the HTML controls. If you use AngularJS, you can also populate the `$scope` in the `variables-fetched` callback and read the values from the `$scope` in the `submit` callback:

My changed HTML:

```
<form>
    <script cam-script type="text/form-script">
        camForm.on('form-loaded', function() {
            camForm.variableManager.fetchVariable('variable');
        });

        camForm.on('variables-fetched', function() {
            $scope.variable = camForm.variableManager.variable('variable');
        });

        camForm.on('submit', function() {
            camForm.variableManager.variableValue('variable', $scope.variable);
        });
    </script>
    <select data-ng-model="variable">
        <option value="option1">option1</option>
        <option value="option2">option2</option>
    </select>
</form>
```